# PHP shell_exec INSERT MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, shell, command-line, wamp

I'm trying to insert some data into a table with shell_exec (on localhost).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$shellExec = 'C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin\mysql -h localhost -u root mm_'.$acname.' INSERT INTO account (acct_name,start_date,active,name,address1,address2,postcode,telephone,website,email,vat_number,vat_amount,start_number,currency) VALUES("'.$company.'","'.$start_date.'","'.$active.'","'.$acname.'","'.$address1.'","'.$address2.'","'.$postcode.'","'.$telephone.'","'.$website.'","'.$email.'","'.$vat_number.'","'.$vat_amount.'","'.$start_number.'","'.$currency.'")';

shell_exec($shellExec);
```

Which runs as:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin\mysql -h localhost -u root mm_robdunne22 INSERT INTO account (acct_name,start_date,active,name,address1,address2,postcode,telephone,website,email,vat_number,vat_amount,start_number,currency) VALUES("sdfsdfy","10-05-2011","1","robdunne22","fsdfs","dfsd","sdf","3423423434sdfsdf","cvxcvdfg","gfgh55ydddd","sdfs","sdfgggaacc","1","pound")
```

On the command line.

This fails - on the command line if i run this it just displays the MySQL help information. I think the problem is that logging into MySQL and the INSERT statement should be separate. They work fine if I split them, however I'm not sure how to make this work - either split into two or as one shell command.

Comment: Why just don't use mysql support built into php?

Comment: Properly quoting command line arguments in Windows is already a daunting task. What you want to do has a name: masochism.

Comment: Also, while we're at it, you should look at prepared statements, and check that $company etc are properly escaped. Finally, if you are on a shared server, you need to check that other users can't see the commands you execute using the task manager (I think that's what it's called; the windows equivalent of top).

Comment: Thanks for the replies @Álvaro G. Vicario was right. Didn't manage to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mySQL documentation, here is an example that looks to accomplish what you need.

```
mysql -u root -p --execute="SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user"
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote `'INSERT INTO [...skipped...] '`